# ASP.NET MVC azure DNS with GoDaddy

Tags: azure, dns, domain-name

I bought a domain name using GoDaddy. (ex: hellopavilion.com)

My virtual machine for Azure and its DNS is hellopavilion.cloudapp.net

I clicked on Domain Manager in GoDaddy and in the Records section > ADD > Type (CNAME).

I See Host, Points to, and TTL.

For Host I wrote **www** and for Points to, I wrote **mydomain.cloudapp.net** and for TTL I selected **1 Hour** and clicked on Save, but an error occured saying:

*"An unexpected error occurred. If this issue continues, contact support."*

I followed some tutorials like [here](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/custom-domain-names-in-windows-azure), but having a hard time applying it to the current Godaddy UI since they are outdated. Anyone know why an error occured? How do I properly map my domain name to the azure DNS?

p.s. tested in IIS Manager in my virtual machine and localhost is working.

[image: test.png]

Comment: I have seen this happen when you have an existing record for the same Host value. See if we can create the entry for some other subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the domain `hellopavilion.com` you had bought?
It seems your order is in progress.

Since I lookup whois result of the domain.
It is still unregistered. So you can't add records.

Comment: It should be the bug  of GoDaddy.  Can you show me the screenshots when you add your CNAME request.

Comment: posted the screenshot

Comment: It looks good unless you have any other recode with host `www`

Comment: yeah i think the Host is the part where the problem occurs. Should I talk to Godaddy customer service?

Comment: Yes if you don't have any other type of record for `www`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123675/discussion-between-qin-and-pavilion).